# how to detect click event on <li> and <img> with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, carousel

I'm applying `glide.js` on my PHP+Javascript project. I want to make it so that when the images are clicked, the page would redirect to different pages. but I can't even catch the click event on the `<li>` or `<img>` tags.. why is that?

here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/glide.core.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/glide.theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fontawesome-5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="glide">
      <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
        <ul class="glide__slides">
          <li class="glide__slide" id="asd1"><img id="asd2" src="/assets/img/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
          <li class="glide__slide"><img src="/assets/img/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
        <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
          </button>
        <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </button>
      </div>

      <div class="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="/assets/js/glide_3.5.2.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    const config = {
      type: 'carousel',
    };
    new Glide(".glide", config).mount();

    const asd1 = document.querySelector('#asd1');
    asd1.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert('asd1');
    });
    const asd2 = document.querySelector('#asd2');
    console.log('asd', asd1, asd2);
    asd2.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert('asd2');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is your id asd1,asd2 ?

Comment: sorry I forgot the id.. I fixed the code

Comment: strange. everything seems right

Comment: Your code should work - if you take out the glide stuff in the above snippet, you'll see the click events are working.  Check your console to make sure you don't have any errors in there which would be stopping your js working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than binding to specific IDs as you do here why not use a delegated event listener ( here I bound it to the document but could easily be the glide container ) and use the `event` to help identify which element received the click and use that as the basis of your redirect?

```js
const config = {
  type: 'carousel',
};
new Glide(".glide", config).mount();


// a delegated listener listening for clicks on elements 
// with .glide_slide class or the image within.

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if( e.target.classList.contains('glide__slide') || e.target.tagName=='IMG' ) console.log( e.target );
});
```

```css
.glider {
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Glide.js/3.2.0/css/glide.core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Glide.js/3.2.0/css/glide.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Glide.js/3.5.0/glide.js'></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="glide">
    <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
      <ul class="glide__slides">
        <li class="glide__slide glider"><img src="//placekitten.com/200/200?image=1" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="glide__slide glider"><img src="//placekitten.com/200/200?image=2" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="glide__slide glider"><img src="//placekitten.com/200/200?image=3" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="glide__slide glider"><img src="//placekitten.com/200/200?image=4" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="glide__slide glider"><img src="//placekitten.com/200/200?image=5" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
      <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
      <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
      <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add events to the li and img elements at the same time.
Try to console.log(event) or console.log(event.element) and debug from there on.